# mysql_fetch_array gives error in while [using ezSQL]

Tags: php, mysql, ezsql

i am new in oAuth and ezSQL.

```
$a = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id ");
$i=0;
while ($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) { 
$oauth_token[$i] = $b["oauth_token"]; 
$oauth_secret[$i] = $b["oauth_secret"];
$i++; }
```

i have $db database and selected rows (etc.). but i am already using ezSQL and mysql_fetch_array($argument).

can anyone help me?

i solved my problem. but i have a new problem.

```
mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\like.php on line
```

Comment: Hey check the query

Comment: $a = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id ");$a = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE id  = ''some thing here...");

Comment: no need parameter to id. i solved my problem. just `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysq*l*i_fetch_array`. but this time gives error `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`